# Conditional probability of a product of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Assume we have two instances $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the random variable $X$ that follow an exponential distribution with mean value 1. These instances are independent.

Moreover, we have two instances $y_1$ and $y_2$ of the random variable $Y$  that follow a uniform distribution with the restriction $y_1>y_2$. To that end, $y_2$ depends on the value of $y_1$.

I would like to calculate the conditional probability that the product of $x_2$ with $y_2$ is higher than a constant $c$, given that $x_1y_1>c$, as in:

$Pr(x_2y_2>c|x_1y_1>c)=?$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Such $y_1,y_2$ don't exist.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? $y_1$ and $y_2$ are different instances of the same random variable. The same applies for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but your initial description was unclear. When restricted to $y_1<y_2$ (I'll switch the indices through-out) $y_i=y_{(i)}$ (order statistics) no longer follows a uniform distribution.